# Tamil Month Dates and Tamil Calendar React Native

Tags: android, ios, react-native, calendar, tamil

I want to display react native calendar along with Tamil month date . is there any possible way to achieve it in react native for android and iOS

I tried React native calendar and added Tamil translated months and week but I couldn't get Tamil month date to display with normal calendar

Comment: What did you try and why didn't it work? Please share some code and more details so people can help you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this may help you.

Refer react-native-calendars official [documentation](https://wix.github.io/react-native-calendars/docs/Intro).

```
import {LocaleConfig} from 'react-native-calendars';

LocaleConfig.locales['fr'] = {
  monthNames: [
    'Janvier',
    'Février',
    'Mars',
    'Avril',
    'Mai',
    'Juin',
    'Juillet',
    'Août',
    'Septembre',
    'Octobre',
    'Novembre',
    'Décembre'
  ],
  monthNamesShort: ['Janv.', 'Févr.', 'Mars', 'Avril', 'Mai', 'Juin', 'Juil.', 'Août', 'Sept.', 'Oct.', 'Nov.', 'Déc.'],
  dayNames: ['Dimanche', 'Lundi', 'Mardi', 'Mercredi', 'Jeudi', 'Vendredi', 'Samedi'],
  dayNamesShort: ['Dim.', 'Lun.', 'Mar.', 'Mer.', 'Jeu.', 'Ven.', 'Sam.'],
  today: "Aujourd'hui"
};
LocaleConfig.defaultLocale = 'fr';
```

Comment: Hello! Welcome to Stackoverflow, We appreciate that your efforts to trying to answer, Links are appreciated but please read and follow this [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) and make edit to your answer.